# HTML quiz game with Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, bootstrap-4, online-game

Hi I'm trying to create an html quiz game with canvas, but I'm new to this thing and I didn't find any documentation to this particular thing.

**Game summary**

The game is set into 5 scenes, every scene is a time period (prehistory, ancient Rome ecc..), and there is only a static image in the background with some shiny points. When the users click on that's point the game zoom on it, and appear a question. When the user answer to the question the scene zoom out and he can click on the next question. When the user has answered all the questions in that scene, the game moves on to the next.

**My Problem**

I can't find a valid documentation about this, and i really don't know where to start. My idea was to use bootstrap and include some plug-in to do this but i didn't find anyone. I know that there are better framework like angular to do this kind of game but I really don't have the time to learn something as that.

Someone as any idea about the better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing people's progress on a database or communicating with Google Classroom (eg. to add scores to assignments? I would personally recommend using Google Apps Script and embedding it on an HTMLsave bag to get rid of the "watermark" that is displayed on top of Apps Script web apps. Here is some documentation to get you started:
[Bootstrap Docs by W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ver.asp)
[Apps Script Overview and Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: I'm using a database, but the link you put here is a simple guide on how to use bootstrap no? This is not my problem, what i need is a way to implement the game on the site with a js plugin or a guide to use canvas for this kind of thing

Comment: Here is a plugin that has some documentation: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Dynamic-Quiz.html  https://github.com/jchamill/jquery-quiz

Comment: This is good but how can i merge this with the canvas game with all the graphics?